# sed: how to insert line after a block of text?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have text file: file.conf

```
### Option: LogFile
#       Name of log file.
#       If not set, syslog is used.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LogFile=

### Option: LogFileSize
#       Maximum size of log file in MB.
#       0 - disable automatic log rotation.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1024
# Default:
# LogFileSize=1
```

And I have tried:

```
sed --posix -e '/\bLogFile\b/{:a;n;/^ *$/!ba;i\LogFile=/tmp/log1.log' -e '}' file.conf
```

And this is working fine, for those option block which is followed by a blank line.

**Problem with this is: at the end of last block if no new line is present, then it dose not insert the line. Here with text LogFileSize.**

How to handle this.

Comment: AFAICS, that's because you told it not to by using `\b` after `LogFile` in the pattern, and `LogFileSize` does not match that because `Size` is part of the word, not a word boundary.  You might also have issues because the `n` command can't read another line when there are no lines left in the file; I'm not certain what it does, but it could very well terminate the command sequence before the insert operation occurs.  I can't help but think that the script would be easier to read if you spread it out over multiple lines.

Comment: add a line at the end by using H; as beginning of your sed script if you can change the script with this. This does not make LogFileSize passing the \bLogFile\b like mentionned by J Leffler

Comment: Perhaps you need to restate your conditions as: *insert* after a block of code before a blank line and *append* after a block of code when the last line of the file is not a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

1. To add after match line:

   ```
   $ sed  '/#.*LogFile=/a\LogFile=/tmp/log1.log'  1.cat
   ```

   will do:

   ```
   # LogFile=
   LogFile=/tmp/log1.log
   ```
2. To add before first empty line:

   ```
   $ sed  '/^$/i\LogFile=/tmp/log1.log'  1.cat
   ```

   will do:

   ```
   # LogFileSize=1
   LogFile=/tmp/log1.log
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your valued answer. :-)

I am trying to make a generalized script to change configuration files. But, not be sure a _# option=_ like text will be present in every configuration files. My intention is: if some description text is present I will adding options after those lines. (I am handling value replacement or new addition of option in other way.)

Comment: @donul updated, but if you wont be satisfied, I'll think yet ))